# Refrescar Página

Tags: ajax, sweetalert

Tengo esta función que guarda datos de un formulario y al guardar o cancelar, alerta al usuario.
necesito implementar `function () {window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN"}`si los datos fueron enviados. 
No entiendo donde colocarlo

```js
      function AlertContactado() {

          var form = $("#FormContactado");
          var url = form.attr("action");
          var data = form.serialize();
          swal({
              title: "¿Seguro(a) que deseas Guardar?",
              text: "¿Realmente que quieres guardar?",
              type: "info",
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: "Si, ¡Guardalo!",
              cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
              closeOnConfirm: false,
              closeOnCancel: false
          },
                   function (isConfirm) {
                       if (isConfirm) {
                           $.ajax({
                               url: url,
                               type: "POST",
                               processData: false,
                               data: data,
                               contentType: false,
                               success: function (result) {
                                   swal("¡Hecho!", "Los Datos se han guardado satisfactoriamente", "success");
                               }
                           });
                       } else {
                           swal("¡Cancelado!", "Usted a cancelado el guardado", "error");
                       }
                   });
      };
```

Comment: En success ya que eso se ejecuta si los datos se enviaron correctamente...

Comment: `success: function (result) {
                                   swal("¡Hecho!", "Los Datos se han guardado satisfactoriamente", "success");
                               },function () {window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN"}` algo así?

Comment: `window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN";` Tan solo pon ese pedazo dentro del success, algo asi: `success: function (result) { swal("¡Hecho!", "Los Datos se han guardado satisfactoriamente", "success"); window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN"; }`

Comment: Y si quieres que te muestre el mensaje antes de que te redireccione lo que puedes hacer es que le puedes meter un: `setTime(function () {window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN"}, xTime); ` para que te muestre el mensaje

Comment: Funciona! Muchas gracias, veré el tema del `setTime`

Comment: Okey entonces te dejo la respuesta y un par de comentarios de como funciona setTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Codigo anterior
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {
        swal("¡Hecho!", "Los Datos se han guardado satisfactoriamente", "success");
        // La función setTime, se encarga de ejecutar algo despues de un determinado tiempo
        // El primer párametro de esta función es otra función que sera lo que ejecute
        // El segundo párametro sera un tiempo en milisegundos, que le indicara cuanto tiempo debe de esperar antes de ejecutar el primer párametro
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN";
        }, 3000)
    }
});
// Código posterior
```

> [Puedes leer mas sobre la  documentación de
>   setTimeOut](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: podrias agregar en tu ejemplo tu solucion una explicacion , no es solo copiar y pegar ; si das una buena explicacion te apuesto que tendras muchos +1

Comment: Okey amigo lo tomare mucho en cuenta gracias